# Stuck while solving $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^2}^{x^3} e^{t^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

I have to solve $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^2}^{x^3} e^{t^2} dt$, and below is what I've done.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^2}^{x^3} e^{t^2} dt$$

$$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{(x + h)^2}^{(x + h)^3} e^{t^2} dt - \int_{x^2}^{x^3} e^{t^2} dt}{h}$$

$$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{x^3}^{(x + h)^3} e^{t^2} dt - \int_{x^2}^{(x + h)^2} e^{t^2} dt}{h}$$

Due to [the mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals),

$$\int_{x^3}^{(x + h)^3} e^{t^2} dt = ((x + h)^3 - x^3) e^{p^2} = (3 h x^2 + 3 h^2 x + h^3) e^{p^2}$$

$$\int_{x^2}^{(x + h)^2} e^{t^2} dt = ((x + h)^2 - x^2) e^{q^2} = (2 h x + h^2) e^{q^2}$$

Substituting,

$$\cdots = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(3 h x^2 + 3 h^2 x + h^3) e^{p^2} - (2 h x + h^2) e^{q^2}}{h}$$

$$= 3 e^{p^2} x^2 - 2 e^{q^2} x$$

How do I clean up $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Why is$$\int_{x^3}^{(x + h)^3} e^{t^2} dt = ((x + h)^3 - x^3) e^{p^2}\quad?$$What is $p$? You should use the [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) to take the derivative.

Comment: @user170231 There must be some rectangle of height $p$ and width $(x+h)^3-x^3$ to match the value of the integral.

Comment: use leibnitz rule and it is just a one line answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set

$$f(x)=\int_0^x e^{t^2}~\mathrm{d}x$$

and notice that, by the FTC,

$$f'(x)=e^{x^2}.$$

Observe now that

$$I(x)=\int_{x^2}^{x^3}e^{t^2}~\mathrm{d}t=f(x^3)-f(x^2).$$

Using the chain rule we thus get the answer to the problem as

$$I'(x)=3x^2f'(x^3)-2xf'(x^2)=3x^2e^{x^6}-2xe^{x^4}.$$

---

To comment on your solution, think about how $p$ and $q$ are defined. In particular, they depend on your $h$ (in the sense that they are in some interval whose length depends on $h$), and so look at what happens to them when $h\to0$ (you should be able to squeeze them), and you should get the same answer as me.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d}{d x} \int_{x^2}^{x^3} e^{t^2} d t=&\frac{d}{d x}\left[\int_0^{x^3} e^{t^2} d t-\int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} d t\right] \\
= & \left(\frac{d}{d (x^3)} \int_0^{x^3} e^{t^2} d t\right) \frac{d}{d x} (x^3)-\left(\frac{d}{d( x^2)} \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} d t\right)\frac{ d}{dx}  (x^2)\quad \textrm{( By Chain Rule)}\\
= & 3 x^2 e^{\left(x^3\right)^2}-2 x e^{\left(x^2\right)^2} \quad \textrm{ (By FTC)} \\
= & 3 x^2 e^{x^6}-2 x e^{x^4}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: A right parenthesis is missing.